# Evaluate a double infinite summation

Tags: number-theory, complex-analysis

> $$
> H=\sum_m\sum_n'\frac{1}{(m-1+nz)(m+nz)}
> $$

The summation of $m,n$ is over $\mathbb{Z}$, and skips $(1,0),(0,0)$，and $z\in\mathbb{H}$ (The upper half plane).

The series comes from Jean-Pierre Serre's **A Course in Arithmetic**. It is a conditionally convergent series, so the summation order affects the result.

Interchanging the order, we get

> $$
> H_1=\sum_n\sum_m'\frac{1}{(m-1+nz)(m+nz)}
> $$

This is easily seen to be $2$.

There are furthermore two series

> $$
> G=\sum_n\sum_m'\frac{1}{(m+nz)^2}
> $$
>   $$
> G_1=\sum_n\sum_m'\frac{1}{(m+nz)^2}
> $$

The motivation was to use $G_1-H_1=G-H$ (As the difference is absolutely convergent, the order does not matter now) to deduce the functional equation $F(-\frac{1}{z})=z^{12}F(z)$ for

> $$
> f(z)=q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)^{24}
> $$

where $q=\exp(2\pi iz)$. But I was stuck on the first summation.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Now on the title.

Comment: Please include the question in the body as well. Titles are meant for titles.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Are you familiar with the notion  of Eisenstein series? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series It seems quite close to it. But I don't see straight away any explicit relation between the two. If you could provide some more details we could help you better.

Comment: Details now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need
$$\pi\cot\pi z=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{z+n}+\frac{1}{z-n})$$
Now

> $$H=\sum_m\sum_n'\frac{1}{(m-1+nz)(m+nz)}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_m\sum_n'\left(\frac{1}{((m-1)/z+n)}-\frac{1}{(m/z+n)}\right)$$

When $m\ne 0,1$, sum with respect to $n$ gives $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{z}(\cot \pi \frac{m-1}{z}-\cot \pi\frac{m}{z})$. When $m=0,1$, we get $\pi/z\cot (-\pi /z)+z$ and $-\pi/z\cot (\pi /z)+z$.

It is now
$$2+2\frac{\pi}{z}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\cot -\pi\frac{m}{z}$$

Let $q(z)=\exp(2\pi i z)$, then $\displaystyle \cot \pi z=\frac{\cos \pi z}{\sin \pi z}=i\frac{q+1}{q-1}=-i-2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^n$. When $m\rightarrow \infty$, $q(m/z)\rightarrow 0$. So the result is exactly $2-2\pi i /z$.